# How can I pass in existing html content to initialize an instance of lexical editor?

Tags: lexicaljs

When using LexicalComposer, the initialConfig accepts an editorState parameter that can be used to pass in some initial content. If this initialContent is a complex html string, I am not clear how to parse it. For a simple string, I have it like below (everything works fine here):

```
const initialState = () => {
  const paragraph = $createParagraphNode();
  const text = $createTextNode(initialContent);
  paragraph.append(text);
  const root = $getRoot().append(paragraph);
  root.selectEnd()}

const initialConfig = {
   namespace: 'HTMLEditor',
   theme: editorTheme,
   onError: (error: Error) => {
    throw error;
   },
  editorState: initialState}
```

Which I then pass in to LexicalComposer. If the string I pass in is NOT a simple string, but rather some html content in the form of a string, and if I do NOT know ahead of time exactly what will be passed in (i.e. I want to parse existing html content created elsewhere) how do I do it? I can't use $generateNodesFromDOM because my editor hasn't yet been initialized.

Answer (score 5):

So to get this to work was a multi-step process.
First I had to create a plugin to load my initialContent, like this:

```js
type Props = { initialContent?: string }   

export const LoadInitialContent = ({ initialContent }: Props) => {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialContent) { return; }
    editor.update(() => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const dom = parser.parseFromString(initialContent, "text/html");
      const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);
      console.log(dom, nodes);
      const paragraphNode = $createParagraphNode();
      nodes.forEach(n => paragraphNode.append(n));
      $getRoot().append(paragraphNode);
    });
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

Next I had to load this within my LexicalComposer, like this:

```js
<LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
  <LoadInitialContent initialContent={initialContent} />
</LexicalComposer>
```

Next, in order to properly recognize the various node types, I had to import the types and list them within the initialConfig for LexicalComposer like this:

```js
...
import { ListNode, ListItemNode } from "@lexical/list";
import { HeadingNode } from "@lexical/rich-text";
...
const initialConfig = {
  namespace: 'Editor',
  onError: (error: Error) => {
    throw error;
  },
  nodes: [ListNode, ListItemNode, HeadingNode]
};
```

And finally I had to import the relevant Lexical Plugins and use them, like so:

```js
...
import { ListPlugin } from "@lexical/react/LexicalListPlugin";
import { RichTextPlugin } from "@lexical/react/LexicalRichTextPlugin";
import { ContentEditable } from "@lexical/react/LexicalContentEditable";
...
<LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
  <LoadInitialContent initialContent={initialContent} />
  <ListPlugin />
  <RichTextPlugin contentEditable={ContentEditable} />
</LexicalComposer>
```

I'm pretty sure I'll have to do the same to be able to "see" Links and other kinds of nodes too.

Comment: The text is being appended twice. Any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: Hard to comment without seeing your code. If you followed the example I posted above the text, should only be appended single time. Perhaps you can post your code here and we might be able to see something that you may have missed

Comment: @DivyanthJayaraj That's happening because you're in a development environment, and the useEffect is firing twice. Try doing this right after `editor.update` and before `const parser = new DOMParser();`

`$getRoot().getChildren().forEach((n) => n.remove());`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for excellent answer from @tolkienfan2
i will optimize it using useRef hook to prevent the useEffect from running twice

```
    import { useLexicalComposerContext } from '@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext';
import { $createParagraphNode, $getRoot } from 'lexical';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { $generateNodesFromDOM } from '@lexical/html';
type Props = { initialContent?: string };

export const LoadInitialContent = ({ initialContent }: Props) => {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
  const isMountedRef = useRef<boolean>(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialContent || isMountedRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    editor.update(() => {
      $getRoot()
        .getChildren()
        .forEach((n) => n.remove());
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const dom = parser.parseFromString(initialContent, 'text/html');
      const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);
      console.log(dom, nodes);
      const paragraphNode = $createParagraphNode();
      nodes.forEach((n) => paragraphNode.append(n));
      $getRoot().append(paragraphNode);
    });
    isMountedRef.current = true;
  }, [editor, initialContent]);
  return null;
};
```

it's better (more efficient) then this solution from @gabriel-graves:

```
$getRoot().getChildren().forEach((n) => n.remove());
```